# How convert Socks to HTTP in Mac OSX?

Tags: proxy

I am using Mac OSX with Socks5 proxy. I would like to config my command line to export http_proxy = XXXX to accelerate my downloading. Are there any tools that can achieve this conversion? I've heard Provixy can do it, but I'm not sure how yet. Can you show me how please?

Thanks.

Jimmy

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 5):

You could try **polipo**.
I use it under ubuntu (it should be also available on Mac) and find it can work with the socks proxy either created by `ssh -D ...` or **shadowsocks**.

```
apt-get install polipo
service polipo start //start polipo service
polipo socksParentProxy=localhost:1080  // your SOCKS local port
export http_proxy=http://localhost:8123
```

Answer (score 3):

You can install it with brew:

```
brew install polipo
```

And open a config file:

```
vim ~/.poliporc
```

Fill it with the content:

```
# your SOCKS local port
socksParentProxy = 127.0.0.1:1080
socksProxyType = socks5

# default port is 8123
# proxyAddress = '::0'
# proxyPort = 9743
```

Start polipo with `polipo -c ~/.poliporc` and now polipo established a http proxy based on your socks5 proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Command line proxy, you can also try **proxychains**. Configure  /etc/proxychains.conf,

```
...
socks5  <server-address> <port> 
#exmaple
#socks5 127.0.0.1 1080
```

then in command line, just run

```
$ proxychains wget <your url>
```